# How to mass-add a 2 letter prefix / namespace to Objective-C Project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, namespaces, naming-conventions

I am using XCode, and have an Objective-C, iOS project with 200+ source files including 2 storyboards and 10 xibs.  This project does not use a 2 letter prefix for its classes.  Now, its classes need to be added to another project which also does not use 2 letter namespacing.  There will be plenty of naming conflicts.

What is the best way to add a 2 or 3 letter prefix to every source file and class in an XCode project?  Are there any automated tools to do this?

Comment: I use manual XCODE->refactor->rename classes interfaces, it will rename all class occurrences, and files .h .m (but still lot of routine work)

Comment: But that only does 1 entity at a time.  Is there a way to do all of them in mass?

Comment: You could write a script, perhaps using `tops`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since no one else is submitting an answer to my question, here is a brute-force solution I have created using UNIX Shell Scripts.

**Step #1**:
Create a "rename_classes.txt" file where each line contains a class name from/to pair separated by one or more tabs.
Example:

```
MyClassA   ZZMyClassA
MyClassB   ZZMyClassB
MyClassC   ZZMyClassC
```

**Step #2**:
Copy and paste the following into a shell script, and then execute the script from the directory containing the XCode project:

```
#!/bin/bash

PROJECT_DIR=.
RENAME_CLASSES=rename_classes.txt

#First, we substitute the text in all of the files.
sed_cmd=`sed -e 's@^@s/[[:<:]]@; s@[[:space:]]\{1,\}@[[:>:]]/@; s@$@/g;@' ${RENAME_CLASSES} `
find ${PROJECT_DIR} -type f \
    \( -name "*.pbxproj" -or -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" -or -name "*.mm" -or -name "*.cpp" -or -name "*.xib" -or -name "*.storyboard" \) \
    -exec sed -i.bak "${sed_cmd}" {} +

# Now, we rename the .h/.m files
while read line; do
    class_from=`echo $line | sed "s/[[:space:]]\{1,\}.*//"`
    class_to=`echo $line | sed "s/.*[[:space:]]\{1,\}//"`
    find ${PROJECT_DIR} -type f -regex ".*[[:<:]]${class_from}[[:>:]][^\/]*\.[hm]*" -print | egrep -v '.bak$' | \
    while read file_from; do
         file_to=`echo $file_from | sed "s/\(.*\)[[:<:]]${class_from}[[:>:]]\([^\/]*\)/\1${class_to}\2/"`
         echo mv "${file_from}" "${file_to}"
         mv "${file_from}" "${file_to}"
    done
done < ${RENAME_CLASSES}
```

Note the following:

- This script **will update all references** to classes found in the
  Project File, XIB files, storyboard files, .h, .m, .mm, & .cpp source files.
- For each modified file, a backup file with the original contents will be created named "[filename].bak".
- This script only renames .h, .m, & .mm files.  .xib files and Storyboards will
  need to be renamed by hand.
- 'PROJECT_DIR' can be set to another directory if desired.
- 'RENAME_CLASSES' should point to the file created in Step #1.
- If there are groups named the same as classes that are being renamed, the groups will be renamed in the project file as well.
- I have used this script on 4+ projects, and it has worked beautifully.

If no one has a better answer at the end of the bounty period, I'll accept this answer (my own).

Comment: Please Note:  This method isn't specific to "prefixing" files.  It can be used to mass-rename files in any manner.  Ex.  (rename FileABC -> NewFileDEF )